# Loop only when between 2 numbers

Tags: vb6

I have been putting off asking this questions as it seemed like such a simple problem I could solve but i have be racking my brains and now cant think. I have tried loads of different combinations of code but cant seem to find the correct one.

My 2 porblems:

- I need to create a loop that will only fire when a variable is between 2 numbers. Example (this does not work) : `Do While SOPickRS.RecordCount >=1 and <=4`
- I need to a variable that monitors what record the loop is on. A counter could work however is there not an actual ADODB variable for it?

My Current Code:

```
While Not SOPickRS.EOF

        Do Until SOPickRS.RecordCount = 4

            'Do Stuff

        Loop

        Do Until SOPickRS.RecordCount = 8

             'Do Stuff

        Loop

        Do Until SOPickRS.RecordCount = 12

           'Do Stuff

        Loop


SOPickRS.MoveNext

Wend
```

GTG has also pointed that RecordCount will not work as it never changes.

Comment: RecordCount is the number of records in the recordset, not the index of the item you are currently looking at, so your Do While loop will either not run at all (if the recordset is empty or contains more than 3 items) or never stop.

Comment: I have just added some more of my current code to save confusion. My Loops are running however I need to limit them so they only run when the Record Count Is between two numbers

Comment: what is the requirement is not clear. As @GTG said, recordcount gives number of records and it does not change, and either loop will not be executed or will not be terminated

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean now. I have updated my question again. (Bottom of post)

Comment: what is wrong with keeping track of the record index you have looped to in a simple variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying for something like this :

```
currentRecord = 1
While Not SOPickRS.EOF

    if (currentRecord  >=1 and currentRecord  <=4)
        'Do Stuff
    end if
    currentRecord = currentRecord + 1
wend
```